# How to export logs to view?

Tags: laravel-4

I am building out an admin page for a Laravel 4.1 application and would like a way to easily access the log file(s).

I tried this:

```
Route::get('logs', function() {
    $logfile = storage_path() . '/logs/laravel.log';
    $logs = file_get_contents($logfile);
    return Response::json(array('logs' => $logs));
});
```

But it throws the following error:

```
{"error":{"type":"UnexpectedValueException","message":"The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), \"boolean\" given.","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/myApp\/vendor\/symfony\/http-foundation\/Symfony\/Component\/HttpFoundation\/Response.php","line":421}}
```

Comment: The code works just fine for me. Do you have the correct permissions to read the `laravel.log` file. If that's not the issue, what does the `admin` filter do? (maybe the problem comes from there; post a full stack trace of the error).

Comment: Yes. The server (www-data) has read and write permissions to the `app/storage` folder and also to the `app/storage/logs` folder and `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` file. I tried this with the default `auth` filter and also with no filter at all. Still the same error. Also, how should I post the full stack trace?

Comment: Hmm, if I simply use `return file_get_contents(storage_path() . '/logs/laravel.log');` it works, I guess the problem is from `Rosponse::json(...`

Comment: Try encoding the contents of the log when returning it `return Response::json(array('logs' => base64_encode($logs)));` to see if it works then. On the client side if you're using JS to handle the response you can use `atob(response.logs)` to decode the data.